# Proving $\arctan(\tan z)=z$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

...Or at least one small part of the proof. Most of the argument is complete, but I am left with one edge case, and perhaps some of you might be able to fill in the gap.

Working from the definitions
$$\tan z = \frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\frac1i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$$
and
$$\arctan z = \frac i2(\log(1-iz)-\log(1+iz)),$$

I wish to prove that $\arctan(\tan z)=z$ when $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $-\frac{\pi}2<\Re z<\frac{\pi}2$. (This is almost the true domain of correctness of this identity, except that it is true sometimes for $|\Re z|=\frac{\pi}2$ as well, due to the choice of branch cuts.) The complex log function has its branch chosen so that $\Im\log z\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

Expanding out the definitions changes the goal to

$$\log(1-i\tan z)-\log(1+i\tan z)=-2iz,$$

and since some simple algebra shows that the exponential of each side is equal, it is sufficient to prove that $\Im[\log(1-i\tan z)-\log(1+i\tan z)]$ and $\Im[-2iz]$ are both in $(-\pi,\pi]$ (so that I can write each side as $a=\log(e^a)$ and use equality of the exponentials to finish the proof).

Now $\Im[-2iz]\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is trivial since we are assuming $-\frac{\pi}2<\Re z<\frac{\pi}2$, and although it is not exactly a one-line proof, I managed to show that $\Im[\log(1-iz)-\log(1+iz)]\in(-\pi,\pi)$ whenever $\Re z\ne0$. This leaves the following case:

> If $z\in\Bbb C$ and $-\frac{\pi}2<\Re z<\frac{\pi}2$, and $\tan z$ is pure imaginary, then $|\Im\tan z|<1$.

From this it follows that $\log(1\pm i\tan z)$ are both real and $\Im[\log(1-i\tan z)-\log(1+i\tan z)]=0$ since $1\pm i\tan z$ will be positive real. Some fumbling with Mathematica reveals that $\tan z$ is pure imaginary only when $z=n\frac{\pi}2+iy$; when $n$ is odd you get $\tan z=i\coth y$ and when $n$ is even it becomes $\tan z=i\tanh y$. Since $|\coth y|>1$ that would violate the boxed claim, but it is excluded due to the restriction $-\frac{\pi}2<\Re z<\frac{\pi}2$, and $|\tanh y|<1$, so if I could prove that $\tan z$ is pure imaginary only when $z$ is pure imaginary, I would be done.

Comment: Another avenue to the proof: It is sufficient to show that $\Re\tan z>0$ for $0<\Re z<\frac{\pi}2$. I thought that decomposing $\tan(x+iy)=\frac{\tan x+i\tanh y}{1-i\tan x\tanh y}$ might help, since $\tan x$ is known positive, but the denominator is not real, so it is hard to tell if the $i\tanh y$ part will make the real part of the whole fraction negative.

Comment: $$\tan(x+iy)=\frac{\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y}{\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y}=\frac{\sin x\cos x+i\sinh y\cosh y}{\cos^2x\cosh^2y+\sin^2x\sinh^2y}$$ This shows that $\tan(x+iy)$ is pure imaginary exactly when $\sin x\cos x=0$; that is, when $x=n\pi/2$. Since you're assuming $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, this means $x=0$; the input is pure imaginary. So we're done?

Comment: @mr_e_man This question is from 7 years ago so I don't really remember this proof anymore, but the result of the work is [public](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/atantan.html) and I guess I managed to finish it. If $z=iy$ then $\tan z=i\tanh y$ so it suffices to show that $\tanh y<1$ (and $\tanh (-y)<1\implies -1<\tanh y$ by symmetry), which we can do by writing it as $$\tanh y=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}$$ and noting that $e^{-y}$ is positive.